# Overwrite Custom Skill to Keep Existing Skill ID and Users

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa-hosted custom skill built with Alexa Conversations (Skill A) that I recently converted to ACDL. While I am testing the Skill's concept with users, I am rewriting the Skill to use the Interaction Model (Skill B) instead of ACDL under a different Skill within the developer console. When I'm done developing, I would like to replace the functionality of Skill A with that of Skill B so that I can keep the same Skill ID along with the users who have enabled my skill. Is this possible?

I assumed I had to "turn off" the Conversation model to detach it from ACDL. When I went into the console, the option to deactivate it wasn't available.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your ACDL skill (Skill A) to include Skill B's interaction model. After converting an Alexa Conversations skill to ACDL and deploying it, the skill's interaction model can no longer be edited in the developer console. Instead, it must be edited with the ASK CLI. You can therefore copy your interaction model from Skill B and use it to replace your ACDL skill's (Skill A) interaction model, which is found in the `skill-package/interactionModels/custom/` directory.

Finally, to ensure the interaction model, rather than ACDL, has control of the dialog at the start of Skill A's skill sessions, change the value of `sessionStartDelegationStrategy.target` in your skill.json file's dialogManagement object to 'skill'.